# Centering a css block

Tags: html, css

This block of css controls the position of some 3rd party images.  They are generated on the fly as a javascript slider.  I need to center it based on another image else where on the page.  I know the left and right dimensions of my reference image.  All I need to do is figure out how to center this block on that.  Is there a way to center this between say 200px and 800px?

```
.pagination {
   display: block;
   margin:26px auto 0;
   width:400px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   left: 130px; 
   position:relative; 
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: tried to hard to understand your question. but i cannot understand, can you provide some html or an example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: maybe you should try explain with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width is 400px (as per your snippet), you could do:

```
.pagination {
   display: block;
   margin: 26px auto 0;
   width: 400px;
}
```

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/Ne9jz/

Comment: hey i think `.pagination` css class created at runtime on some slider thing.. he has not explained properly, so changing the class will be not possible.

Comment: I see what you mean, yeah if that's the case we need more details.